# MongoDB update and increment operation, when update data is an empty hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

When using Ruby-on-Rails with ruby version 2.2.0, MongoDB version 3.0.5,

I am experiencing a weird behaviour when trying to execute an update query contains both update and increment, when the update data is an empty hash:

When running the command:

(1) `db.collection.update({'user_id' => 123456}, {'$set' => {}, '$inc' => { 'counter' => 1 }}, {:upsert => true})`

The value of the field `counter` left as it was (no change).

When running the command:

(2) `db.collection.update({'user_id' => 123456}, {'$inc' => { 'counter' => 1 }}, {:upsert => true})`

The value of the field `counter` is incremented by 1, as expected.

Can someone please  explain to me why command (1) has a different result than command (2)?

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.update({'user_id' => 123456}, {'$set' => {}, '$inc' => { 'counter' => 1 }}, {:upsert => true})
```

outputs `'$set' is empty. You must specify a field like so: {$mod: {<field>: ...}}` exception

This might be the reason why your counter is not incremented.

Which version of mongodb are you using  Mine is 2.6

Comment: $set: {} is rejected by the update framework since 2.6 version.

Comment: I use 3.0.5. Thanks for the answers! I knew something was wrong with update using empty hash, didn't know what (the empty hash is an edge case in my program).